# Help with SQL QUERY OF JOIN+COUNT+MAX

Tags: sql, mysql

I need a help constructung an sql query for mysql database. 2 Table as follows:

```
tblcities (id,name)
tblmembers(id,name,city_id)
```

Now I want to retrieve the 'city' details that has maximum number of 'members'.

Regards

Comment: What should the query return if there are multiple cities that have the highest number of members (i.e. ties)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tblcities.id, tblcities.name, COUNT(tblmembers.id) AS member_count
FROM tblcities
LEFT JOIN tblmembers ON tblcities.id = tblmembers.city_id
GROUP BY tblcities.id
ORDER BY member_count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Basically: retrieve all cities and count how many members each has, sort by that member count in descending order, making the highest count first - then show only that first city.

Comment: Thought about that too, but maybe there are **more than one** city with the maximum number of members...

Comment: @rsenna - The OP implies they only want one: `the 'city' details that has maximum number of 'members'`. *The* city as opposed to cities. Unless the OP says otherwise, it is logical to assume that ties should be ignored.

Comment: @Thomas: How I would ignore ties? Randomly picking one? Ignoring all items that tie, and going to the second place? Sorry, but the only possible logical assumption is that ties *are* indeed possible, and that all valid answers should be given! And remember: the objective of a Q&A site is to give answers to common questions. That implies that this question *may also be asked by other people*. And I'm sure most of them will be interested about ties...

Comment: @resenna - We have to go on what is actually in the OP. The OP states that they want one and only one ("The" city). If they want to account for ties (meaning show all cities with the highest count), that's different and that should be included in the question. The problem is that with MySQL, the solution to account for ties is very different and will perform much worse than the one to simply get the highest because it lacks ranking functions. Thus, being explicit about what is desire is quite important.

Comment: @Thomas: Well, the only thing I could add is that, if you do work with creating commercial software, I feel sorry for your users... ;) I believe that requirements are *always* incomplete, and it is our job not only to find those holes, but also to give a proper solution to them. And to me that's also the case here - the OP simply was not aware of the possibility of a tie. But I see your point, performance is also important, and I also agree it is up to the OP to choose the best answer.

Comment: @rsenna - Actually, I do write commercial software and having a specification is critical especially when there is a wide variance in the solutions. In this case, the difference in performance could easily be an order of magnitude. Keep in mind, that under normal circumstances, we would have a much better idea of *why* they want this information. This is a developer forum and we have to presume to a degree that the OP has vetted the reasons for wanting what the ask and are looking for how to implement it. Still, it's a valid question that I'll ask in the comments to the OP.

Comment: Thanks marc, it helps a lot. By the way, just for confirmation, it should be "GROUP BY tblcities.id" Instead of "GROUP BY tblcities" , right?

Comment: @rana: woops, right. good catch. I'll change the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Terrible, but that's a way of doing it:

```
SELECT * FROM tblcities WHERE id IN (
    SELECT city_id
    FROM tblMembers
    GROUP BY city_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (
        SELECT MAX(TOTAL)
        FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
            FROM tblMembers
            GROUP BY city_id
        ) AS AUX
    )
)
```

That way, if there is a tie, still you'll get all cities with the maximum number of members...

Comment: Painful, but would handle the ties nicely. Good catch.

Comment: rsenna, yours one worked. However I faced performance issue with this, taking longer time than marc's. And Thanks for giving the solution for multiple max results. However, currently one will fullfill my needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ...
From tblCities As C
    Join    (
            Select city_id, Count(*) As MemberCount
            From tblMembers
            Order By Count(*) Desc
            Limit 1
            ) As MostMembers
        On MostMembers.city_id = C.id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select top 1 c.id, c.name, count(*)   
from tblcities c, tblmembers m 
where c.id = m.city_id 
group by c.id, c.name 
order by count(*) desc
```